# Baby rudin theorem 9.32

Tags: matrices, analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, matrix-rank

> Suppose ,, are nonnegative integers, $≥$,$≥$,$$   is a $\mathscr b$ mapping of an open set ⊂$^{}$ into $^{}$, and $′()$ has rank $r$ for every $∈$.
>
> Fix $∈$, put $=′()$, Let $_{1}$ be the range of $A$, and let $$ be the projection in $^{}$ whose range if $_{1}$. Let $_{2}$ be the null space of $$.
>
> Then there are open sets $$ and $$ in $^{}$, with $∈$,$⊂$ and there is a 1-1 mapping $$ of $$ onto $$(whose inverse is also of class $\mathscr b$) such that
>
> $$(())=+()   (∈) $$ where $$ is a $\mathscr b$ mapping of open set $()⊂_{1}$ into $_{2}$.

Here is the proof:

> If $r=0$, Theorem 9.19 shows that $F(x)$ is constant in a neighborhood $U$ of $a$, and the equation above holds trivially. With $V=U$,$H(x)=x$,$ \phi(0)=F(a)$

I couldn't understand that why  the fact that $F(x)$ is a constant in a neighborhood $U$ of $a$  when r is equal of 0 makes this equality: $$(())=+()   (∈) $$  trivial.

I also don't understand why $\varphi(0)$ is equal of $F(a)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think Newton would not have a problem with a question about derivatives :D

Comment: What is a "b mapping"?

Comment: @PaulFrost continuously differentiable